# populate an array from dataset

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dataset

Hi can anyone provide me with a simple example (or point me in the direction of an example) of how to fill an array with a specific column from a dataset within VB.NET?

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on the controls of a dataset within VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is documentation on the dataset class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

you can access a dataset which is strongly typed with:

```
dataSetName.dataTableName(rowIndex).ColumnName
```

if your dataset isn't strongly typed then you can use:

```
dataSetName.tables("tableName").Rows(rowIndex).Item(columnIndex)
```

Comment: I used the non-strongly typed example and have run into a problem where the column in the database is designed as varchar(20). Is there an equivalent to varchar in VB.NET?

Comment: i don't quite understand the problem. You could update your question with the code example? In vb.net you would use a string to hold data from a varchar column